problem with importing json file in my vue project
I've imported a given API which is in JSON format and it doesn't show the data on the webpage. What could be the issue?
<script setup>
import JobData from '@/jobs.json'; 
import { ref } from 'vue';

const jobs = ref(JobData);

</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id">
    {{ }}
  </div>
</template>


First of all, nothing being displayed is expected.  {{ }} doesn't display anything.  Assuming your real code is not like this, then there is no other obvious issue with the code.  Syntactically, it's fine.  Maybe the JSON is malformed or the import path is wrong.  We need more debugging information like if there's any console errors and/or more information about your environment setup, enough to make the problem reproducible.

What is your transpiler configuration? Json files might be excluded from the build
